# what does "everyone's money" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> she would make him feel she had never fallen before - and I should think it's likely she never had. She would not be **everyone's money**. You may be sure that she let Mr. Quayne know that her little life was from now on entirely in his hands.

<sup>(*The Death of the Heart*, by Elizabeth Bowen, 1938)</sup>

I thought "she would not meet any random man" 
Is it an idiomatic expression? anybody knows the meaning?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a common expression in modern English. Though it may be 1930 slang.

Reading the wider context, "she" is Irene, and the mistress of Mr Quayle (the father in law of Anna who is narrating this part). She is expressing her devotion to Mr Quayle. She is expressing both her devotion, and her dependence on Mr Quayle, hence she doesn't have any other source of income except Mr Quayle. In fact, we know, that Irene is already pregnant with Portia, the heroine of the story. The author is filling in a bit of the backstory here.

The book is not a simple read, I noticed several other old usages of words, such as "capitulations" meaning a set of conditions or promises.